# What happens if you perform a publish in Sitecore desktop while on the web database

Tags: publishing

If I am using the Sitecore desktop and have switched to view the web database in the bottom right corner, what happens if I perform a publish (assuming I have only the web DB as a publishing target).

Comment: That's a really good question! I was curious enough to decompile some code and from what I see it may behave like standard publishing from `master` to `web`. Meaning - if e.g. there are publishing restrictions and the date already passed, the item will be removed from the `web` database. And cache will be cleared. That is assuming you have only `master` and `web` database (no extra publishing targets defined under `/sitecore/system/Publishing targets/`. Would be more interesting if you add option to publish to `master` again ;) No tests executed so I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: And from what I see if you set `/sitecore/system/Publishing targets/Internet` as not publishable (e.g. publishing restrictions or workflow), and make sure it's not there in `web` database anymore, clicking publish after switching to `web` desktop would do nothing.

Comment: My experience is that it is just like master to web. I have accidentally created item in web and then published. My new accidental web items got deleted. Then I realized I was on the web database.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like web compares to web when you publish from the web database. Installed a module with a lot of changes and published from web. The event looked the same in the log.

### Sitecore Log

From web:

> 4788 22:43:54 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Publish, root: null,
>      languages:en, targets:Internet, databases:web, incremental:false,
>      smart:true, republish:false, children:false, related:true
>
> 4788 22:43:54 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): [Publishing]: Starting to
>      process 1 publishing options

From master

> 16620 22:45:36 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Publish, root: null, languages:en, targets:Internet, databases:web, incremental:false, smart:true, republish:false, children:false, related:true
>
> 16620 22:45:36 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing options

### Publishing Log

But when I look in the publishing log it tells a different story.

from web (No items updated):

> 4788 22:43:54 INFO  [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing options
>   4788 22:43:54 INFO  [PublishOptions]: root:null, language:en,    targets:Internet, database:web, mode:Full, smart:True children:True,    related:True
>   3204 22:43:55 WARN  SitePublish detected. PublishContext was overridden with DisableDatabaseCaches=True.
>   3204 22:43:55 INFO     Starting [Publishing] - AddItemsToQueue
>   3204 22:43:55 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - AddItemsToQueue in 0 ms
>   3204 22:43:55 INFO  Starting  [Publishing] - ProcessQueue
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Finished [Publishing] ProcessQueue in 3720 ms
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Publish Mode : Smart
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Created : 0
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Updated : 0
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Deleted : 0
>   3204 22:43:59 INFO  Skipped : 4593

from master (73 updated, 503 created):

> 16620 22:45:36 INFO  [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing
>   options
>   16620 22:45:36 INFO  [PublishOptions]: root:null,
>   language:en, targets:Internet, database:web, mode:Full, smart:True children:True, related:True
>   10640 22:45:37 WARN  SitePublish detected. PublishContext was overridden with DisableDatabaseCaches=True.
>   10640 22:45:37 INFO  Starting [Publishing] - AddItemsToQueue
>   10640 22:45:37 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - AddItemsToQueue in 0 ms
>   10640 22:45:37 INFO  Starting [Publishing] - ProcessQueue
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO  Finished [Publishing] - ProcessQueue in 65023 ms
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO  Publish Mode : Smart
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO  Created : `503` 
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO Updated : `73` 
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO  Deleted : 0
>   10640 22:46:42 INFO  Skipped : `4523`